# CV2.dnn_Detection in Raspberry_Pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

my cv version is 4.1.0, thus I got  this type of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Obj_Detection/ObjectDetectorModule.py", line 12, in <module>
net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'dnn_DetectionModel'
```